# dplyr use select() helpers inside mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd to make a new variable which represents the sum (or other function) of many other variables which all start with "prefix_". Is there a way to do this neatly using these select() helpers (e.g. starts_with())?

I don't *think* mutate_at() works for this since I'm just trying to create a single new variable based on many existing variables.

My attempt:

```
df %<>%
  mutate(newvar = sum(vars(starts_with("prefix_"))))
```

This of course doesn't work. Many thanks!

A reproducible example:

```
mtcars %<>% 
  rename("prefix_mpg" = mpg) %>% 
  rename("prefix_cyl" = cyl) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = sum(var(starts_with("prefix_"))))
```

Intended output would be mtcars$newvar which is the sum of prefix_mpg and prefix_cyl. Of course I could just explicitly name mpg and cyl but in my actual case it's a long list of variables, too long to name conveniently.

Comment: I need a more general solution, as the actual function is more complex than summing.

Comment: reproducible example: mtcars %<>% rename("prefix_mpg" = mpg) %>% rename("prefix_cyl" = cyl) %>% mutate(newvar = sum(var(starts_with("prefix_"))))

Comment: yes, that's the same error I get, and that's why I'm asking the right way to do it if anybody knows. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `starts_with` with the `select` call and put them in the `rowSums` function. `.` is a way to specify the object from the output of the previous pipe operation.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  rename(prefix_mpg = mpg, prefix_cyl = cyl) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = rowSums(select(., starts_with("prefix_"))))
```